# start couchbase on osx 10.8 but couchbase menu dis not display

Tags: mac-osx, couchdb

I follow the instruction at

http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-1.8/couchbase-admin-basics-running-macosx.html

to run couchbase on osx 10.8

but the menu of couch base never display

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Couchbase 2.0.0 on my OS X install without problem.
May be you can try with this release.

Please uninstall the 1.8 before installing the 2.0 by stopping the server, and delete the "~/Library/Application Support/Couchbase" and "~/Library/Application Support/Membase" folders.

Comment: Probably this would be better as a comment, also, I'd include the latest version you are running with success.  As this any answer would be archival, the latest version now will not be the latest version at a future time when somebody is looking at the answer.